# Debug Magento Adminhtml in Zend Studio XDebug

Tags: magento, ide, xdebug

I'm currently using Zend Studio for Magento development.I can able to debug frontend with xdebug.But xdebug for admin is not working.Breakpoints and variables are not showing for the admin.

Could anyone shed some light on how to debug Magento admin?

Comment: what is your Debug configuration details ... ?

Comment: is this using symlinks somewhere?

Comment: Yes.I use symlinks for the modules.